# Render react virtualized list of side-by-side items

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flexbox, electron, react-virtualized

Trying to render a list of max 400 items in flexbox-like manner (breakpoints) in rows with multiple items side-by-side - depending on the available width.

I am using material-ui components and had to start using react-virtualized because of performance issues. Each item is a small piece of UI that also expands/collapses with some edit functionality.

I have been trying to (mis)use the (react-virtualized) Table and calculate the number of Columns dynamically (based on screen width) and sprinkle my items over each grid Cell. I cannot seem to get the Columns to align next to each other on one Row - I must be doing something very simple very wrong. Looked at the samples too, but I could not see any significant differences compare to my code.

I would rather use the existing flexbox (or grid) css services to get this working. I just do not know how to integrate this into a virtualized list/table.

Here is some code of how I try to `render` the Table, but I hope to get rid of it and use some flexbox magic instead:

```
<div style={{height: "100%"}}>
    <AutoSizer>
        {({height, width}) => {
            this.grid = new GridCalc(this.props.items.length, width);

            return (
                <Table 
                    disableHeader={true}
                    rowCount={this.grid.rowCount}
                    rowGetter={this.getRow}
                    height={height}
                    width={width}
                    rowHeight={80}   <= this also has to be dynamic
                >
                    {this.grid.columns.map((value: number, index: number) => 
                        this.renderColumn(index, value))}
                </Table>
                );
            }}
    </AutoSizer>
</div>
```

The `renderColumn` looks like this:

```
<Column
    key={colIndex}
    dataKey={colIndex}
    width={width}
    cellRenderer={this.renderCell}
    cellDataGetter={this.getCellData}
/>
```

The `renderCell` is stubbed out to remove complexity:

```
<div>{props.cellData.name}</div>
```

The `getRow` returns a sliced array of objects for each item on a row and `getCellData` methods selects the correct object from that (sub) array for the specific cell. These objects are stored in a Redux store and attached to the control with a normal redux-`connect` call.

Let me know if you need to see specific code/details.

Comment: Link to a CodeSandbox (or similar) where I can see this working. Happy to take a look but looking at partial code is inefficient. That being said, this example might be similar to what you're trying to do (unless I misunderstand you) http://plnkr.co/edit/zjCwNeRZ7XtmFp1PDBsc?p=preview

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. I will try that approach. Thanx!

Comment: Yep, got it working. Thanx Brian.